# How to make inner join with two conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables in mysql database they are like following:

```
USERS : id, username
POSTS : id, post, poster_id, posted_id
```

Now I want to get the last 10 posts with the username of the poster_id(the man who wrote the post) and the username of the posted_id(the owner of the wall where the post has been written)

I use this query :

```
SELECT posts.*,users.username as poster_username FROM posts
INNER JOIN users on posts.poster_id = users.id 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

but as you can see I just get one username for the poster_id
is there a way to get the username of the posted_id within the same inner join statement??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should join user for twice:

```
SELECT posts.*,
       u1.username as poster_username,
       u2.username as posted_username
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users u1 on posts.poster_id = u1.id 
INNER JOIN users u2 on posts.posted_id = u2.id 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

The only requirement is to assign an alias to each table